# Is it possible to determine the chipset of a USB device?

Tags: drivers

If I run `lsusb` I see my USB WiFi device.

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 7392:a812 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd

Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x7392 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd
  idProduct          0xa812 
  bcdDevice            2.00
  iManufacturer           1 Realtek
  iProduct                2 Edimax AC600 USB
  iSerial                 3 00e04c000001
  bNumConfigurations      1
  ...
```

If I run `lshw` I see the *driver* used by that device is `rtl8812au`

```
*-network:1
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 3
   bus info: usb@1:12
   logical name: enp0s20u12
   serial: 74:da:38:b9:77:3c
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8812au ip=192.168.0.105 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11AC
```

Using `journalctl` in Arch I see the *driver* registered is `rtl8812au`.

```
Sep 30 12:22:20 archlinux kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8812au
```

[My understanding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391919/do-vendor-id-and-product-id-alone-determine-the-driver-used-for-a-usb-device) is that self-identified fields from a device like vendor id and product id inform the system what sort of driver should be loaded for a device.

But how do I know the chipset? A driver [may cover multiple chipsets](https://wiki.debian.org/rt2800usb), right?

So my device could very well be using one of a wide range of chipsets covered by that particular driver.

The sample output I posted makes me think my device is probably an `rtl8812au` chipset considering the driver for it is named so specifically.

But the [rt2800usb driver](https://wiki.debian.org/rt2800usb) really intrigues me. It covers such a wide range of chipsets. If my system showed that the `rt2800usb` *driver* was being loaded, I feel like it wouldn't be nearly as clear what the chipset was.

Is there any way to *really* know the particular chipset of my device without somehow opening up the device and examining the chip?

Comment: There is no way, unless the driver covering multiple chipsets can perform identification of the chipset (which depends on the chipsets, often you can read a register for chipset and/or version). Some drivers can, and some even tell you in `dmesg`.

Comment: For some reason, I thought my question was unique, but I see my question really is a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757295/how-can-you-identify-the-chipset-of-a-usb-device-in-linux and that the answer by  @dirkt is correct. It seems that there is no reliable or consistent way to determine the chipset of a USB device