# How to check if a given driver kernel module supports a given device?

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules

I am trying to find an appropriate driver for a USB WiFi adapter that is reported by `lsusb` as

```
0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

On [WikiDevi](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Main_Page) it is [described](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Realtek_RTL8812BU_USB_Module) as "Realtek RTL8811AU Wireless 802.11ac 1x1 USB 2.0".

There are multiple repositories that seem to provide drivers for RTL8811AU, for example [this](https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux) one (it is based on [this](https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU) one that claims to support rtl8811AU). However, I would like to check the compiled module if it supports the device before trying to install it into the kernel (it is someone else's system that I am trying to mess with).

From searching online I concluded that it should be enough that the output of `modinfo` command for the driver module return a line of the kind

```
alias:          usb:v0BDApA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

which would contain the correct vendor ID (`0BDA`) and the correct product ID (`A811`).

How reliable is this method of checking compatibility of drivers with devices?  Is this how the kernel selects the driver?

Is the exact match of both vendor and device IDs necessary?  For example, I tried first installing `rtl8812au-dkms` package with `apt-get` (on Ubuntu). However, the output of `modinfo 8812au | grep A811` was

```
alias:          usb:v7392pA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

-- the device ID is ok, but the vendor ID does not match.  Does it mean that this driver will not work with this device?

Comment: Please run `modprobe -rv 8812au` then `modprobe -v 8812au` does the module load correctly?

Comment: @GAD3R, are you asking about the module from `rtl8812au-dkms`?  I tried these commands, there were no messages except "`insmod /lib/modules/4.13.0-32-generic/updates/dkms/8812au.ko`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method is reliable, that is how the kernel (or `udev` and `kmod`) chooses a module to load: when a new device appears (including at boot time, when all devices are probed), it looks for a module with a `modalias` matching the device descriptor.

If `modinfo` lists an alias for a module which matches your device, then that means the module claims to support the device. In your case, the module supports devices matching 7392:A811 (and perhaps others which don’t match your `grep`), but not your device, so it appears `rtl8812au-dkms` won’t be much help (at least in its current state)... The [Linux USB registry](http://www.linux-usb.org/) is currently offline, so I can’t check any further. Note that aliases are a first level of filtering, and don’t absolutely guarantee support — modules use their own probe functions when they initialise, and those can use other pieces of information. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/391919/86440) for more details, and [the kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/usb/usb.html#usb-header) for information on everything which can feature in an alias.

(The similarity in identifiers does suggest the driver could support your device too, so you could try adding the ids to the module to see what happens.)